# trigger writing for different column names in two different tables

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I am creating a trigger and understand how to do this if the columns in two different tables have the same name.  Ex, I write a trigger that if a new record is added in the salary column for table A to take the salary from table A and insert that as salary in table B.

What I don't understand how to do, is populate that data into table B if that table has a different column name.  So I have table A that the column name is salary and table B where the column name is pastsalary.

How do I write the trigger to be able to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the difference between the two.. Your insert statment would just reflect the column you want to insert into:

```
insert into tableB(pastsalary) values (:new.salary);
```

Comment: When I try to do that I get PLS-00049 bad bind variable

Comment: I figured it out, I just had a piece of code backwards.  Thanks for the assistance though as that helped me realize it.